# How to connect entitities in a database

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am trying to design a database. Check the image

As you can see in the picture I have Companies, Trusts, Partnerships and some similar legal entities. 
A company can have one or more Company Directors (a director can be a trust, partnership or even another company)
A trust can have one or more Trust Beneficiaries (a beneficiary can be a company, partnership or even another trust)
A partnership  can have one or more partners (a partner can be a company, trust or even another partnership)

The description of the mini-world is that the users will input data about legal entities and then they are going to create the relationships between them

There are many reports that need to be produced. The most frequently used ones will be the ones that they will need to see a legal entity and its structure e.g a company with its directors and see details of each director. A recursion tree exists here as a company can have as a director another company

The LegalEntity table has FK in Company, Trust, Partnership and any other new Entity (I have about 20 more). Based on the above scenario I would get the LegalEntityId and it would give me the LegalEntityType. e.g If the LegalEntityType is a Trust I have to query Trust table to get more details. Having a switch statement every time I would need to retrieve something is not the easiest and the best way I think.

[image]

Comment: Images of your database are useless. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) And of course we don't know what you want to do here either.

Comment: What are you expecting for output? Not trying to be rude here, I am trying to get you to see that helping is challenging because we have almost no detail. Is this a new database you are building or an existing one?

Comment: I need to connect Companies, Trusts, Partnerships together. I believe I was very clear in the business logic. Let say I need to find who is a director of a company with Id 1. It might be a trust, partneship or another company. based on the design I posted I can't find who is the director and what type is it (company, trust, partnership etc..) New database

Comment: Coonect them according to the business requirements. There can be zero, one, or multiple connections between each pair of tables, and this is 100% defined by the business model. What do you want to do? What are you modeling? What are the use cases?

Comment: Given the data structure that you provided I don't think this is possible. You have no data that relates a row with another row. You may think it is clear but I don't understand your question. Are you designing the database or trying to write a query?

Comment: You need to add much more info for us to understand what you are doing. Downvoting.

Comment: I dont know how else to explain it. I am designing the database.

Comment: @The Impaler. What type of info do you need?

Comment: You did fine from Company to Director. That is a clear relationship. But to map a director to any of these different entities requires some interesting bits. You need to have a DirectorType for sure so that you know from a row in Director what it relates to. It could be as simple as 1 means Partnership and 2 means Trust. You would then another column for PartnershipID and another of TrustID. You need that to maintain foreign keys. Do yourself a favor and use TrustID etc instead of ID in one table and change the name in other tables.

Comment: But really you should put the image in your question instead of a link to your google drive.

Comment: If I add DirectorType it means that every time I do a Select in I have to add conditions. If DirectorType = 1 then join with Partnership table, If DirectoryType=2 then join with Trust. Is that efficient?

Comment: You would do a left join to both and include DirectorType as a predicate in that join.

Comment: This is a minified version of the database. I have another 20 tables like partneship and trust and each one has its own logic (Companies have directors, Trusts have beneficiaries, Partnerships have partners and every other Entity has similar requirements) Do you think is efficient to do a left join with 20 tables ?

Comment: That is impossible to answer without a mountain more knowledge of what you have going on. Might not be a bad idea to hire a consultant to help you get this in the right direction.

Comment: As I said In my below answer, First things, First. It will be easier to have in mind how this world is logically "made" and which are the questions that you have to answer. After,  we can physically model it in several ways,  more or less redundant,  more or less normalized....

Comment: Your question is not clear. What does "connect these tables together" mean? PS Please clarify via post edits, not comments.

Comment: Again, from which sketch you crafted this ER? Describe here all the specifications that u know, i e, the mini world start point

Comment: As @philipxy said, even if u comment, edit too your post to better comply with the new understanding and clarify your question, so anyone that is first viewing will not need to read all these comments

Comment: @codejunkie, see **EDIT 2** @ my answer

Comment: You are still not explaining what you want.

Comment: And i'm suspecting  that we are in a GroundHog Movie... this is a [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 0):

The way to link them is through a Foreign Key.

But before dig in it, I seems to me that you are trying to deal with a Physical Data Model without understand first the Logical Data Model; had you visit this [resource](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) ever?

Company Directors, Trust Beneficiaries and Partners are specialized cases of the generic case contact; but for that, you have to exclude of contact table all fields (members) that tell that contact is a physical person (like Gender, DOB, all that I'm not seeing).

So, just add a fk_contact field at CompanyDirector, TrustBeneficiary and PartnershipPartner; after, link the id contact field as Primary Key to all these Foreign Key fields, in a conditional 1:N relationship.

This way, you'll have a N:N link in-between Partneship-Contact, Trust-Contact, Company-Contact; the in-between tables are Associative-Entities expressed as tables.

Of course it depends of what DB you are using to implement it physically.

And, sincerely, I don't think that the question was so bad-formulated...

**EDIT 1** - based on scattered comments:

> The Entity table would have FK in Company, Trust, Partnership and any
>   other new Entity

That is why Entity isn't a good and descriptive name... in theory, all Actors/Objects can be mapped to some Entity...

> Having an switch statement everytime I would want to retrieve
>   something is not the easiest and the best way I think

That's why we have to separate the logical and physical models... even if something is correct at Logical level, we may model it other way physically, based on how much we'll access some attribute/field; sometimes we denormalize a table, including some attribute that belongs logically to a child table just to not have to pay the price of disk or network access...

And it will be easier if you can post this 2 fundamental pieces of info:

1. What is the description, plain-English, no-pseudo-code, of your case, i e, the mini-world?
2. What are the reports that you have to produce, i e, which questions u have to answer?

**EDIT 2:** here instead of commenting because of the size of my doubts:

@codejunkie, it seems to me that LegalEntity in your model is only an attribute of the other actors/classes: Trust, Company and Partnership tables has the same fields.

Focusing only in Partnership / PartnershipPartner tables:

is it possible this record?  related to the tuple

```
PartnershipPartner.PartnershipId = Partnership.Id 

PartnershipPartner.LegalEntityId <> Partnership.LegalEntityId
```

If not, I think that a better and more representative way is:

One big table LegalEntity that has all the common attributes of Trust, Company and Partnership; accessory tables in a 1-0..1 with it for the exclusive attributes.

And TrustBeneficiary, PartnershipPartner and CompanyDirector in a similar structure, and what they share probably is the Contacts table that was in the schema before.

The recursion will be implemented is the same way of the classic case of Person being Father Of Person; the role will become an associative entity.

**EDIT 3:** - based on comments @Feb/01, 2019

One crucial thing that I didn't asked or noticed: Are the tables already populated with real data, and you are trying to figured out how to link them? If it is the case, this will change things a lot.

But, if it is not the case:

> Trust, Company and Partnership have only Name, Country as common
>   attribute and phone. They have a bunch of other properties ... ...none of them are common.

Understood; but this do not deny that they are specializations of a generic Entity; now I'm thinking aloud, trying to organize the scattered pieces that I have:

1. LegalEntity seems to me that it is a Generic entity type/class or Supertype Entity;  Trust, Company and Partnership narrow down - and "speciates", biologically speaking - the scope of it;
2. Even at the risk of talking about very basic matters - let me know if this is the case - here is a simple example that seems to me to parallel your case:   think about a generic entity Physician and its specialized entities - cardiologist, hospitalist, internal medicine, etc...; and Physician usually is a specialization case of Person, or Contact; Patient too is a specialization case of Person, or Contact; and Physician may even become a Patient! 
   Here, we are talking about roles in real world.
3. The fact that you see abstractions called Trust, Company and Partnership with some central common attributes and a lot of different attributes, do not tell us if we should encapsulate then in a generic class/entity, as I'm tending or do the opposite, as your image shows. Your "report needs", the attributes and relationships that you need to represent and preserve are the guide to the ideal logical design(s).
4. Only after we have to, or can, turn our attention to the physical design.
5. But all seems mixed up in your question; this may caused the downvotes, as per comments.

Back to the comment:

> PartnershipPartner.PartnershipId = Partnership.Id you are correct.

OK

But there is one fact that isn't smelling good:

```
PartnershipPartner.LegalEntityId <> Partnership.LegalEntityId you are again correct.
```

I do not understand it: all the LegalEntityType instances (from the same table name) can be applied (through the LegalEntity table) to all tables? I understand
Trust, Partnership and Company receiving the same LegalEntityType attribute, but not if TrustBeneficiary, PartnershipPartner and CompanyDirector can receive the same LegalEntityType instances when it is performing another role. If this is the case, and even if it isn't ;) it is better to edit your post and add some Report examples and/or some table/sheet examples, better if with denormalized records.

**EDIT 4:**
Based on comments after feb 2, 2019:

I think that it's a closer representation of what you need:
[image: Class diagram based on our conversation]

Comment: Ok. Now I understood better your question: You will do a 
"FROM CompanyDirector as M INNERJOIN  Contact as N On M.fk_contact
= N.id WHERE"
The above will physically implement the logical view, that's the beauty of SQL

Comment: Can you edit your question and add which DB management you are using? If you have Access it may be simple to model and post the mdb/accdb;  this way will be easy to edit and add some example queries.

Comment: Ok. In few hours I'll can sit at a table to eat this problem!

Comment: Trust, Company and Partnership have only Name, Country as common attribute and phone. They have a bunch of other properties which I didn't post for simplicity but none of them are common. PartnershipPartner.PartnershipId = Partnership.Id you are correct. PartnershipPartner.LegalEntityId <> Partnership.LegalEntityId you are again correct. TrustBeneficiary, PartnershipPartner and CompanyDirector can be Contacts but also any Trust, Partnership or Company

Comment: The question is not clear. It should be commented on, downvoted & close voted, not "answered" (guessed at). Posting answers on unclear questions leads to messes like this page.

Comment: No the tables are not populated. I am in the design stage.
Yes you are right LegalEntity is a Supertype entity.
Let me tell you one basic requirement. I need to open a Company A. Find its directors. If the director is another company (Company B) I need to see that company's directors(There I see CompanyC and TrustA). I open TrustA and I see set as a Beneficiary another (Company D). I open Company D....... 
Also "Trust, Partnership and Company receiving the same LegalEntityType attribute" no Trust has LegalEntityTypeId = 1, Partnership LegalEntityTypeId = 2 and Company LegalEntityTypeId = 3

Comment: @philipxy, I see your point... XY questions may become mess. But as per last comment, I think codejunkie is starting to see the end of tunnel

Comment: @MarceloScofano thanks again for your reply. can you tell me which database tool you are using? Need to understand what 0..1 <<Is A> means, 0..* and 0..1.

Comment: @codejunkie: start on the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) link; there you will learn about cardinality constraints and its several representations. The above modeling tool was Visio, but only because I have and it is easy. Usually I use Access to do what you did on your question; it is very straightforward to model and query.
And for a general, yet far from superficial, approach to DB design, Steve Roman's Access Database Design & Programming was a watershed resource for me.